# Xamarin - Is it possible to use x:Name on xaml element wrapped in OnIdiom?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I have the following scenario, where I wish to work with 2 different labels, depending on the device I am using (phone or tablet).

```
<ContentPage xmlns:local="namespace;assembly">
  <ContentPage.Content>

  <Label x:Name="someLabel" Text="Not important"/>
  <!-- some views here -->

    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="View">
     <OnIdiom.Phone>
        <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="{Binding InvoiceURL}"/>
      </OnIdiom.Phone>
     <OnIdiom.Tablet>
        <Label x:Name="myLabelTablet" Text="{Binding InvoiceURL}" />
      </OnIdiom.Tablet>

    </OnIdiom>

    <!-- some views here -->

  </ContentPage.Content> 
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code I wish to execute, however it will not build due to errors:

```
public MyPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      someLabel.Text = "Hello World";

      if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
        doSomething(myLabel);
      else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
        doSomething(myLabelTablet);
    }
```

The errors I get are as follows:

```
The name 'myLabel' does not exist in the current context
The name 'myLabelTablet' does not exist in the current context
```

What would be a good approach to solve this problem?
What is the reason I get these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting x:Name on the `OnIdiom` element and accessing its `Phone` and `Tablet` properties.

```
  <Label x:Name="someLabel" Text="Not important"/>
  <!-- some views here -->

    <OnIdiom x:Name="myLabel" x:TypeArguments="Label">
     <OnIdiom.Phone>
        <Label Text="{Binding InvoiceURL}"/>
      </OnIdiom.Phone>
     <OnIdiom.Tablet>
        <Label Text="{Binding InvoiceURL}" />
      </OnIdiom.Tablet>

    </OnIdiom>

    <!-- some views here -->

  </ContentPage.Content> 
    </ContentPage>
```

and in the code behind

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    someLabel.Text = "Hello World";

    if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
      doSomething(myLabel.Phone);
    else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
      doSomething(myLabel.Tablet);
}
```